# can't get xml child of child using curl_setopt

Tags: php, xml, loops, oop, foreach

Say I have a xml file like the one below:

```
<objectlist>
    <objectcode>OP#0003</objectcode>
    <objectid>0001</objectid>
    <objecttype>Test object</objecttype>
    <object>
        <info>
            <id>001</id>
            <name>Some name</name>
            <value>5</value>
        </info>
        <properties>
            <shopdetails>
                <desciption>
                    <header>Test</header>
                    <text>This is some text about the object</text>
                </desciption>
                <price>4</price>
                <currency>Dollar</currency>
                <weight>500</weight>
                <gramSymbol>mg</gramSymbol>
            </shopdetails>
        </properties>
    </object>
</objectlist>
```

How do I get all the information out of this XML file using `curl_setopt()`? I tried it with a foreach loop, but it failed. It only gets the information from: *objectcode, object id and objecttype*. 
My script is only able to get information from childnodes of the root but not children of child nodes. I used this script for my project:

```
    <?php
Class xmlObject{    
    public function xml_From_URL() {
        require_once 'dbconnect.php'; 
        $config[CURLOPT_URL] = "http://localhost/example.xml";
        $config[CURLOPT_VERBOSE] = 0;
        $config[CURLOPT_SSLVERSION] = 3;
        $config[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = FALSE;
        $config[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 2;
        $config[CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION] = 0;
        $config[CURLOPT_HEADER] = 0;
        $config[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = 1;
            //-- config section --//
        $tuCurl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($tuCurl, $config);
        $data = curl_exec($tuCurl);
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
            //-- Loops --//
                //-- 1 --//
        foreach($xml -> object as $row){
            $id = $row -> id;
            $name = $row -> name;
            $value = $row -> value;   
            echo("<b>Objects</b></br>");
            echo($id."<br>");
            echo($name."<br>");
            echo($value."<br>");
        }
                //-- 2 --//
        foreach ($xml -> description as $row) {
            $header = $row -> header;
            $text = $row -> text;
            echo("<b>description</b><br>");
            echo($header);
            echo($text);
        }
                //-- 3 --//
        foreach ($xml -> shopdetails as $row) {
            $header = $row -> price;
            $text = $row -> currency;
            $weight = $row -> weight;
            $gramsymbol = $row -> gramsymbol;    
            echo("<b>description</b><br>");
            echo($header);
            echo($text);
        }
        curl_close($tuCurl);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to update your PHP code that parses the XML data - cURL only provides the XML data, doesn't parse it. You are using [simplexml_load_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) to create a [SimpleXMLElement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php). You just need to access properties a little differently.

Instead of accessing `id` from `$row` like this:

```
$id = $row->id;
```

we need to access the node between `<object>` and `<id>` - i.e. `<info>`

```
$id = $row->info->id;
```

And similarly for the other properties. Also, you can move the `curl_close($tuCurl);` up right after the call to `curl_exec` since cURL isn't parsing the XML data - simplexml is. You can see this in action (without the data fetching with cURL) in this [phpFiddle example](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/svqh-5w9z). For more information, refer to the [PHP documentation for SimpleXML elements on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

```
<?php
Class xmlObject{    
    public function xml_From_URL() {
        require_once 'dbconnect.php'; 
        $config[CURLOPT_URL] = "http://localhost/example.xml";
        $config[CURLOPT_VERBOSE] = 0;
        $config[CURLOPT_SSLVERSION] = 3;
        $config[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = FALSE;
        $config[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 2;
        $config[CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION] = 0;
        $config[CURLOPT_HEADER] = 0;
        $config[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = 1;
        //-- config section --//
        $tuCurl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($tuCurl, $config);
        $data = curl_exec($tuCurl);
        
        //now that we have set $data, we can close the cURL request
        curl_close($tuCurl);

        $xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

        foreach($xml -> object as $row){ 
            //access these properties from the info childnode  
            $id = $row->info->id;
            $name = $row->info->name;
            $value = $row->info->value;   
            echo("<b>Objects</b></br>");
            echo($id."<br>");
            echo($name."<br>");
            echo($value."<br>");
            //access these properties using the properties childnode
            $header = $row->properties->shopdetails->desciption->header;
            $text = $row->properties->shopdetails->desciption->text;
            echo("<b>description</b><br>");
            echo($header."<br>");
            echo($text."<br>");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you it worked for the actual script I'm working on.